# string-length() of regex-group XSLT 2.0

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0, string-length

I have a file which contains a text like this

> text +++ text ++ text + text

I want to substitute +++ with an element which takes into account the number of + for each group. 
I have used this xslt

```
...
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\+)+">
<xsl:matching-substring>
<gap reason="illegible" quantity="{string-length(regex-group(1))}" unit="character"/>
</xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
...
```

my desidered result is

```
text <gap reason="illegible" quantity="3" unit="character"/> text <gap
reason="illegible" quantity="2" unit="character"/> text <gap
reason="illegible" quantity="1" unit="character"/> text
```

but apparently my regex matches always only one and I get this:

```
text <gap reason="illegible" quantity="1" unit="character"/> text <gap
reason="illegible" quantity="1" unit="character"/> text <gap
reason="illegible" quantity="1" unit="character"/> text
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regex="(\++)"` to make sure the full string forms the group.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex usually works for matching consecutive `+` character nicely. But you are only picking the one character in the group `()`. That's why you are always getting `quantity="1"` is matched.

So change your regex into this one:

```
([+]+)
```